# how to get sharedpreferences value in edittext from another activity in android for signin

Tags: android

how to get sharedPreferences values like name and password from another activity and get in another activity in editText for furter use.

Actually i want to sign in to another activity using sharedpreferences.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sign in using shared preferences.

Follow these options
1: Get data from EditText in your signin activity. Like

```
string username = ed1.getText().toString();
string password = ed2.getText().toString();
```

then get data from shared preferences username and password

now compare both et

```
if(username.equals(sharepreferencesusername) && password.equals(sharedpreferencespassword)){
 goto next activity...
```

}